# Clearing EmguCV's image buffer

Tags: c#, multithreading, emgucv, raspberry-pi3

I'm working on a project using EmguCV which requires capturing images from a camera and processing them, looking for certain things in the image. The processing takes up about ~.2 seconds, and is the biggest time-sink in the application so we're looking into making the capturing/processing different threads to speed up the overall process.

We've already tried the VideoCapture.ImageGrabbed event handler, and calling Retrieve, as well as setting up a threaded loop of our own calling QueryFrame and any other capturing method we can find.

Most of the threaded solutions end up causing empty images (not caught by the .IsEmpty property of the Mat, though, for some reason), which end up as images saved with 0 bytes.

After this, we tried simplifying but ran into an issue where the camera is always a few seconds behind, due to the buffer internal to the library. This leads to my question: is there a way to refresh the buffer, or clear it of memory? We cannot dispose of the capture object because of the time overhead for creating the object. Any tips about threading the capturing and processing are welcome as well, though the other suggestions I've found around this site about similar situations have not led to much success.

A brief example of the code we're using

```
_capture.ImageGrabbed += GrabFrames;
...
public void GrabFrames()
{
    Mat image = new Mat();
    _capture.Retrieve(image);
    ProcessThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(StartProcess));
    ProcessThread.Start(image);
}
...
public void StartProcess(object image)
{
    Mat img = (Mat)image;
    Process(image);
    img.Dispose();
}
```